# POSIX way to convert user input with utc offset to calendar time

Tags: c, timezone, posix

Is there a POSIX way how to convert a user input with UTC offset into time_t? I was hoping for something like

```
strptime( buf, "%Y-%m-%d-UTC%O", &input_time );
```

where %O would be the UTC offset.

Unfortunately the `tm_gmtoff` extention to `struct tm` doesn't seem to be available on Solaris (10), is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POSIX way to handle timezone information apparently is to set the environment variable *TZ*. Hence, I've chosen to set *TZ* with the user specified timezone prior to working with the time functions:

```
/* Get actual time */
time( &now );

/* Backup time zone */
old_tz = getenv( "TZ" );

/* Set user time zone */
setenv("TZ", zone_s, 1);

/* Get time components in user timezone */
comptime = localtime( &now );

/* Set time */
sscanf(time_string, "%d:%d", &x, &y) );
comptime->tm_hour = x;
comptime->tm_min = y;
comptime->tm_sec = 0;

/* Set date */
sscanf( date_string, "%d-%d-%d", &x, &y, &z );
comptime->tm_year = x-1900;
comptime->tm_mon = y-1;
comptime->tm_mday = z;

/* Restore time zone */
setenv( "TZ", old_tz, 1 );
```

Cheers,

Martin.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to copy the string, search and replace the UTC offset with one of zero, parse both times and take a difference with `difftime(...)`.

There's probably a clever technique out there, but right now I'm short on coffee.

Comment: The only problem is that to get the time difference, you need to have a date time time_t. However, it's not possible to parse a datetime string with an UTC offset - at least not with POSIX, is it?